# How fast can you rush the "Full Crew" achievement?

Tags: achievements, the-witcher-3

After over 90 hours of playing The Witcher 3, I realized that I made a bad choice early on, which blocks me from getting the [Full Crew](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Full_Crew) achievement in this playthrough.

Should this be the only achievement I'll be missing in the end, I'll consider replaying the game on the easiest difficulty and rushing this achievement for the sake of completion. Since this is one of the few missable achievements, I assume I am not the first one to do this. How long will this roughly take me?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps4/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/faqs/73988) GameFAQs guide that says "40hrs+", so that's the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a savefile from the [Nexus](https://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/3169) that has all the requirements for Full Crew and is made just before achieving it. You can make a free account here, get the save, insert it in the [save file's location](https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/613958868360805461/) and get the achievement.

These save files are uploaded for most of the achievements, helping those like you, who accidentally missed them. Of course many people use it to cheat, but I think your case is the textbook example of why they are worth it and how to use them legitimately :)

Comment: But that wouldn't give the satisfaction of achieving it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that it's a cheat. I only suggest this method because if he played through the game and only was not able to achieve Full Crew because a bad choice early in the game, he deserves it. I think in these cases you can spare the 10-20 hour long playtime for the one achievement you missed.

Comment: I still wouldn't agree, @Annosz , played through the entire game an additional time just to unlock a single outfit (not in this game, but another one). So, I think achievement hunting should involve dedication rather than cheats.

Comment: Then I think we can agree to disagree :) I hope my answer helps to those who think like me, and I hope the ones who think like you will have the best feeling of satisfaction after getting the achievement.